# How to change the "MuiStepConnector-alternativeLabe" in mui stepper?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I built a stepper in Hebrew using material, and the line starts from left to right and not from right to left (after I changed everything from right to left) I checked using the element and saw that to solve the problem you need to change MuiStepConnector-alternativeLabel and set: left: calc (50% + 20px);
Right: calc (-50% + 20px).
How do I implement this in code, I can not get this tag in sx or createStyles.
I would appreciate help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPCpJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Stepper
            className={Media ? classes.paperRootMobile : classes.paperRoot}
            activeStep={activeStep}
            alternativeLabel={true}
        >
            {steps.map((label, index) => {
                const stepProps = {
                    completed: activeStep > index,
                };

                if (isStepSkipped(index)) {
                    stepProps.completed = false;
                }
                return (
                    <Step key={label} {...stepProps}>
                        <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
                    </Step>
                );
            })}
        </Stepper>

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>
createStyles({
    root: {
        width: '100%',
        direction: 'ltr',
    },
    paperRoot: {
        backgroundColor: '#e2e8ea',
        paddingRight: '20rem',
        direction: 'rtl',
        paddingLeft: '20rem',
        fontWeight: 900,
        '& .MuiStepConnector-root ': {
            left: ' calc(50% + 20px)',
            right: 'calc(-50% + 20px)',
        },
    },
})
```

);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you look at the documentation. Mui has great guides about styling components, that can be done in many ways. You may try different ways and apply the one that is best for you.

Start with this basic guide: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/

**RTL Support** - Mui also has a great built-in right to left support. This guide explains how to transform **all** Mui components to RTL:
https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/right-to-left/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I know the mui's support for rtl The problem was that the compote itself does not support Hebrew and if you change it to Hebrew then the stepper does not look good.
I finally managed to solve after I got to the specific component through createStyles, it was just that his div was inside the stepper so I did not know what to give in the style itself.
Now it works thanks.